# How can I find elements using testing-library's findByText() when those elements are under a div with a higher z-index?

Tags: reactjs, cypress, react-testing-library

My team is using `react-joyride` for a feature tour in our `react` application. Essentially, `react-joyride` overlays a `<div>` with a very high `z-index` and a semi-transparent (`rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)`) color over the entire DOM. This has the effect of making the page appear 'faded' and also makes it non-interactable (several other `<div>`s are used to highlight a small section of the page and render a tooltip).

I'm writing an integration test for this feature tour using `@testing-library/cypress`. Using `cy.get()`, I can select DOM elements under the joyride `<div>`, but `findByText()` always fails with `Unable to find an element with the text`. I've tried a few things, none of which work:

```
findByText(content)
```

```
const pageContainer = cy.get('div#pageContainer')
pageContainer.findByText(content)
```

```
const pageContainer = cy.get('div#pageContainer')
pageContainer.within(() => findByText(content))
```

Is there an option I'm missing? Something like `findByText(content, { hidden: true }`? I can understand why `testing-library/cypress` thinks the elements can't be found, as there is another `<div>` on top of them, but the elements are visible in the literal sense, and I would like to force `findByText()` to find them...

For some additional content, in our `package.json`:

```
"@testing-library/cypress": "^6.0.0"
"cypress": "4.10.0"
"react-joyride": "^2.2.1"
```

our `cypress.json`:

```
{
  "chromeWebSecurity": false,
  "defaultCommandTimeout": 15000,
  "nodeVersion": "system",
  "screenshotOnRunFailure": false,
  "trashAssetsBeforeRuns": false,
  "video": false,
  "viewportHeight": 1200,
  "viewportWidth": 1920,
  "watchForFileChanges": false
}
```

and we're starting cypress with a simple `cypress open`.

Comment: Do you see visually the text that matches exactly `content` when you run the tests without headless mod?

Comment: Yes, when running `cypress` in an actual browser (Chrome) I can see the text exactly. The elements are visible in the literal sense of the word, there's just a `<div>` with a higher z-index on top of them.

Comment: mm I don't see in the documentation how an overlapping div could leave the text unfound. Maybe `contains` would work better, try `cy.get('div#pageContainer').contains(content)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be something wrong with your app configuration.

Looking at the react-joyride demo page, the joyride elements are siblings of the actual app page, not a parent of (unless I miss-read your description)

```
<body>

  <div id="root">
    // app being demo'd is here 
  </div>

  <div id="react-joyride-portal">
    // joyride overlay is here
  </div>

  <div id="react-joyride-step-1">
    // joyride controls are here
  </div>

</body>
```

Running the following all works (except for unchained `findByText(content)`)

```
it(''finds "V2"'', () => {

  cy.visit('https://react-joyride.com/')

  /* Move to first step */

  cy.contains('button', 'Start').click()
  cy.contains('button', 'Next (1/5)').click()
  cy.contains('div#react-joyride-step-1', 'Next (2/5)')

  /* Find some page content */

  const content = 'V2'

  cy.contains('span', content)
  cy.get('div.star-burst span').contains(content)

  cy.get('div#root').contains(content)

  cy.get('div#root').findByText(content)

  const pageContainer = cy.get('div#root')
  pageContainer.findByText(content)
  // pageContainer.within(() => findByText(content))   // fails, invalid syntax
  pageContainer.within((container) => cy.wrap(container).findByText(content))

})
```

---

**Finding "Our Projects"**

```
it('finds "OUR PROJECTS"', () => {

  cy.visit('https://react-joyride.com/')

  /* Move to first step */

  cy.contains('button', 'Start').click()
  cy.contains('button', 'Next (1/5)').click()
  cy.contains('div#react-joyride-step-1', 'Next (2/5)')

  /* Find some page content */

  const content = 'OUR PROJECTS'

  cy.contains('body', content)

  cy.get('div.demo__section.demo__projects').contains(content)

  cy.get('h2').contains(content)

  cy.get('div#root').findByText(content)

  const pageContainer = cy.get('div#root')
  pageContainer.findByText(content)
  pageContainer.within((container) => cy.wrap(container).findByText(content))

})
```

Comment: To clarify, our app does have the correct DOM structure (`#root` is a sibling of `#react-joyride-portal`), it's just that when you run the feature tour, `react-joyride` creates a `<div>` - `.react-joyride__overlay` - in `#react-joyride-portal` which covers the entire page and has a higher z-index than the rest of the content.

If you try running your example with `const content = 'OUR PROJECTS'` instead you'll see that it fails.

Comment: The overlay doesn't prevent Cypress from finding the element, the test works pretty much the same way even when the sought content is visually under the overlay. Please post your failing test targeting `https://react-joyride.com`.

Comment: The other thing to consider is async loading of content - it's not clear if `.findByText(content)` uses Cypress' retry mechanism to wait for content loading, but `cy.contains('body', content)` will do so.

Comment: From https://github.com/testing-library/cypress-testing-library, the commands do use cypress' built-in retry mechansim.

I'm a nincompoop, and when I replaced 'V2' with 'OUR PROJECTS' in the first test, I neglected to note that `cy.contains('span', content)` and `cy.get('div.star-burst span').contains(content)` would obviously no longer work.

If I ever figure out what is wrong in our app, I will post back here, but for now, I'm accepting this answer, as it is most correct - this *should* work.

Comment: Cheers, thanks for the clarification on cypress-testing-library retries.

Comment: It turns out that I am braindead stupid - I had misspelled the text I was looking for. Wow wow wow wow. What a waste of everyone's time. Apologies ya'll.

Comment: @Zarjio Yaaaaaah, we've all been there. Glad you got it.

Answer (score 1):

If it's in the DOM, `findByText` will find it. Are you sure the text exists? Is it broken up? If you do something like,

```
const world = "World"

<div>Hello {world}</div>
```

It will be rendered as separate pieces of text in the DOM, so `findByText(/Hello World/)` would come back with nothing.